# Firebase cannot found the 'firebase-admin' module when run firebase serve

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am running my app locally and i am having this error:

```js
"i  Starting emulators: ["functions","hosting"]
⚠  Your requested "node" version "8" doesn't match your global version "12"
✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
✔  hosting: Emulator started at http://localhost:5000
i  functions: Watching "/Users/nico/Documents/nexow/nexow-api-firebase/functions" for Cloud Functions...
⚠  Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin'
Require stack:
- /Users/nico/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nico/Documents/nexow/nexow-api-firebase/functions/node_modules/express-firebase-middleware/lib/auth.middleware.js:10:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
⚠  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)"
```

I've already done all the NPM installs, but no way...
A few hours ago it worked and recently stop working. My partner is running the same code and it works for him.

Anyone know where is the problem?

This is my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "*",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, and the issue was opened on github [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1489)

So the work around is to downgrade your system to node8 as it is the engine you want to use.